# Encycled image shifting (translation)

Tags: java, opencv, translation

I want to translate an image so that pixel (x,y) would get value of the (x,y+1) pixel, but (x, mat.height) would get (x, 0) value. It seems that usual translate method doesn`t support such operation. Is there any way to do it faster than in this code?

```
    for (int i = 0; i < map.size().width; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < map.size().height; j++) {
            if (j != map.size().height - 1) {
                map.put(j, i, map.get(j + 1, i));
            }else{
                map.put(j, i, map.get(0, i));
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the whole class

```
public class Map3 extends Function {
//    max = 254 at (136,380)

    public Map3() {
        InitMapFromFile();
    }

    @Override
    public void InitMapFromFile() {
        try {
            map = Imgcodecs.imread("resources/map3.jpg");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Image load error");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void UpdateMap() {
        for (int i = 0; i < map.size().width; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < map.size().height; j++) {
                if (j != map.size().height - 1) {
                    map.put(j, i, map.get(j + 1, i));
                }else{
                    map.put(j, i, map.get(0, i));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure map.put(j, i, map.get(j + 1, i)) compiles using java ?

Comment: Yes, I`ve checked, but it takes about 150 ms per each 400*400 pixel mat. That isn`t totally bad, but I wonder if there is a faster way.

Comment: use java arrays they are definetly faster than maps

Comment: "map" here is just a name for some opencv mat

Comment: can paste the complete code with input